# Google Maps Autocomplete Javascript get city only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a autocomplete Searchbox on my page if i type Hoover(city). It's  returning this address    Hoover, AL, United States, instead of whole addresss I want to capture only city name.

Hoover, AL, United States

I need Hoover only

Google Map javaecript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                   function initialize() {
                      var input = document.getElementById('address');
                      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                   }
                   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


                   function initialize() {
                  var options = {
                          types: ['(cities)'],
                          componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
                         };


                     var input = document.getElementById('address');
                     var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
                }
</script>
```

Comment: If you look at the response data, you will see the various keys provided by Google.  The content is not always consistent, but if you try something like `address_components.0.short_name`, you may win more than you lose.

Comment: thanx for reply now I have tried with jquery it's working  http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/City-Autocomplete-Plugin-with-jQuery-Google-Places-API.html